# Why there is a difference in parse tree output generated from api and GUI provided in stanfordNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using 'stanford-corenlp-full-2013-06-20' api to generate parse tree as given below

```
private String text= "Heart attack causes reduced lifespan average";
Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
coreNLP.annotate(annotation);
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
    Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
    tree.pennPrint();
}
```

It is showing sub sentence 'S' as shown below

```
(ROOT (**S** (NP (NNP Heart) (NN attack))
             (VP (VBZ causes)
                 (**S** (NP (VBN reduced) (NN lifespan) (NN average))))))
```

But When I try to parse the same sentence using the GUI provided by 'stanford-parser-full-2013-06-20' it is giving a different tree (It seems right one) as given below

```
(ROOT (**S** (NP (NNP Heart) (NN attack))
             (VP (VBZ causes)
                 (VP (VBN reduced) (NP (NN lifespan) (NN average))))))
```

Can some one point out why they both are showing two different outputs though they both belong to same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stanford parser will output different results depending on the number of annotation tasks you are asking it to do ([Source](http://rants.tempura.org/2013/03/12/stanford-core-nlp-parsing.html)).  All that is required to get parser output is the sentence split, tokenization, and parse tasks.  However, if you run sentence spilt, tokenization, part-of-speech tag, and parse tasks all together you will get different results.

So the CoreNLP annotation is going to add the POS tagging as well by default, giving you different parse results than the parse only task.

In my experience working with parse trees and both forms of output neither method is strictly better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to get the same parse tree from coreNLP as given in the link.
I am actually trying to extract triples from the parse tree as given [link](http://ailab.ijs.si/delia_rusu/Papers/is_2007.pdf) here. In case if you come across this use case of extracting triples from the parse tree then it would be great help to me if you can share those details.

Comment: I'm a little reserved about how conceptually sound the idea of a 'triplet' is, but If you are looking at finding them then what you probably want is the output of [Stanford Typed Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml).  It should be able to give you subjects, verbs, and predicate arguments.